# How to get \listoffigures and \listoftable numbered in toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, texmaker

I am currently finishing up my thesis but encountered a problem with my layout. My lof and lot are listed in my toc but not numbered like the other sections. Also they are skipped by the numbering of other section and it looks like this in my toc:

...

10 Bibliography

List of Figures

List of Tables

11 Attachements

I already used the \usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind} to get my bibliography numbered but cant figure out how to do the same for the lof and lot.
Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Maybe you can add a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: The other solution is to use `\addcontentsline{toc}{...}`, although getting on the right page is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

If your only use of [`tocbibind`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocbinind) is to include the bibliography in the ToC, then you might just as well go without it and adjust the macros/environments associated with these elements to use `\chapter` instead of `\chapter*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A caption} \end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Abc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```